# Game-maker - Timer System Room Transfer

Tags: timer, game-maker

**How do you transfer a timer's value from one room to another in Game-maker?**

I have a working timer system that counts up, but when I change rooms the timer count resets. Why does the timer count reset?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that the timer is connected to is obviously not set to persistent (which will enable it to remain throughout all the rooms, with all of its previous data).

To enable persistence in an object:
[image]

If it is connected to a controller object it should be easy to make it persistence but if it is part of a lesser object I recommend having it in a separate object to help with room changes (an object set to persistent of course).

Comment: Creating a game in college for an assignment so quite new to this. Thanks for the assitance.

Comment: No problem, I've been using GM for 3 or more years